# connection timed out; no servers could be reached nslookup

Tags: nslookup

```
nslookup 192.168.56.81
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

There is setting in hostfile and `resolv.conf` .
Ip is pinging.

`/etc/sysctl.conf`     --> data is present.

```
kernel.domainname=domain name   
kernel.hostname=hostname
```

`/etc/sysconfig/network` --> hostname file entry is present.

Comment: And what **is** the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts` respectively?

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf   --> nameserver dnserverip    and  /etc/hosts --> having public ip , private ip and scan ip